# If a real valued function is convex in each of its two arguments, can we prove that it does not have an interior maximum?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

If function $f:[0,1]^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is convex in each of its arguments separately, can I then show that there is no interior maximum of $f(x,x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$? That is, the maximum of $f(x,x)$ for $x \in [0,1]$ is either at $x=0$ or $x = 1$.

Comment: $f=0$ has an interior $\max$.

Comment: Try $f(x,y) = (x-\frac12)(y-\frac12)$.

Comment: @copper.hat: regarding f=0, I should refine the question and talk about a non-trivial interior maximum. Regarding the example, the function f(x,x) is convex and maximized at the corners. .

Comment: It may be that for the answer to my question to be positive, one would need to add some structure to f(x,y) so that the cross derivative is not too high.

Comment: Sorry I meant $f(x,y) = -(x-\frac12)(y-\frac12)$.